# Selecting single attribute of elements from a list object based on another Hashset's element

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list object type of some class,

```
class person
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string regid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

List<person> pr = new List<person>();
pr.Add(new person { id = "2",regid="2222", name = "rezoan" });
pr.Add(new person { id = "5",regid="5555", name = "marman" });
pr.Add(new person { id = "3",regid="3333", name = "prithibi" });
```

and a HashSet of type string,

```
HashSet<string> inconsistantIDs = new HashSet<string>();
inconsistantIDs.Add("5");
```

Now i want to get only all the **regid**s from pr list that contains the id's in the inconsistantIDs HashSet and store them into an another HashSet of type string.

i have tried but can only get all the person that has the id's in inconsistantIDs list(This is only an example).

```
 HashSet<person> persons = new HashSet<person>(
            pr.Select(p=>p).Where(p=>
                    inconsistantIDs.Contains(p.id)
                ));
```

Could anyone help me out there?

Comment: What is your desired result? You say you want "only all the *regid*s", but that's a string property, why is `persons` a `HashSet<person>` then?

Comment: my desired result is to only take the regids from the pr list based on the id that is under inconsistantIDs. e.g here i want to get the regid='5555' from pr list based on id 5 in inconsistantIDs @TimSchmelter

Comment: this is all i can done yet but its not my desired output. its and example persons a HashSet<person> @TimSchmelter. my dsire output is only to get the regids not the entire person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regIDs = from p in pr join id in inconsistantIDs on p.id equals id
             select p.regid;
HashSet<string> matchingRegIDs = new HashSet<string>(regIDs); // contains: "5555"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your desired output, but I will try anyway:

```
HashSet<string> persons = new HashSet<string>(
            pr.Select(p=>p.regid)
              .Where(p=> inconsistantIDs.Any(i=>p.Contains(i))));
```